# Change substance look and feel in Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

i am using Substance look and feel plugin for Swing, whenever i change the theme by either

```
SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin(new BusinessBlackSteelSkin());
```

or by :

```
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(L);
    frame.setCursor(
            Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(twisting_frame);
```

borders show up for lists and panels on the GUI, i tried to call validate(),pack(),repaint() and nothing works !! the theme is changing but ugl borders show up, will appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the type of `frame`, but [`setCursor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setCursor%28java.awt.Cursor%29) should work. For reference, here's a working example:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656395 */
public class CursorTest extends JPanel {

    public CursorTest() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("CursorTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CursorTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turn form visibility on and off

```
setVisible(false);
```

and then

```
 setvisible(true);
```